# How to convert array of numbers to array of letters based on modulo

Tags: python, arrays

So I want to transform an array of numbers that sends each number to either the letter A or B depending on whether that number is divisible by 4 or not.

I tried

```
def dicti(x):
    if x%4==0:
        return "A"
    else:
        return "B"

def test(array):
    ar=np.empty([len(array)])
    for i in range(len(array)):
        ar[i]=dicti(array[i])
    return ar

q=[[1,2,3]]

print test(q)
```

but this returns the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-e3de74ca2e41> in <module>()
     18 #print ogksp(G,'source','target',1,"weight")[0][1:5]
     19 #print q[0][0]
---> 20 print test(q)

<ipython-input-85-e3de74ca2e41> in test(array)
     11     ar=np.empty([len(array)])
     12     for i in range(len(array)):
---> 13         ar[i]=dicti(array[i])
     14     return ar
     15 

<ipython-input-85-e3de74ca2e41> in dicti(x)
      1 def dicti(x):
----> 2     if x%4==0:
      3         return "A"
      4     else:
      5         return "B"

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: What's your expected output?  Is it a numpy array with same dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have an extra nested list, you should just use `q = [1,2,3]` instead of the extra list `q = [[1,2,3]]`. But more concisely you can do this in a list comprehension

```
def dicti(x):
    return ['A' if i%4==0 else 'B' for i in x]

>>> dicti([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

If you have specific values you want to map to, you can use a dictionary as well

```
def dicti(x):
    mod = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}
    return [mod[i%4] for i in x]

>>> dicti([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

In the special case where you basically want to map the number to sequential letters, you could do some arithmetic with `chr` and `ord`

```
def dicti(x):
    return [chr(i%4 + ord('A')) for i in x]

>>> dicti([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])      
['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What if we want to place more cases in dicti? I.e. 'A' if i%4==0, B if i%4==1, C if i%4==2, D if i%4==3?

Comment: Inside of `dicti` set a variable `output = []`. Then say `for i in x:` (indent) `if i % 4 == 0:` (indent) `output.append('A')` (outdent) `elif i % 4 == 1:` (indent) `output.append('B')`, and continue like that for all your cases. Then outdent and `return output`